# How I can reverse-proxy http(s) requests using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, http, reverse-proxy

I am developing an http "middleman" (aka reverse proxy) using nodejs. So far I made a basic server listening to http and https:

```
const http = require('node:http');
let https = require('node:https');


const app = (req,res)=>{
  // Forward the request to respecitve http
};

http.createServer(app).listen(80);
https.createServer({
  // typical https options ommited for siplicity
},app).listen(443);
```

In my case, I just want to forward the incomming request to actual server. I mean, if I receive a http GET request for `yahoo.com` just forward it to actual yahoo.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is:

```
const http = require('node:http');
let https = require('node:https');

const getProtocol = (req) => {
    if(req.protocol) return req.protocol;

    return req.secure ? 'https':'http';
};

const app = (req,res)=>{
    const http_handler = getProtocol(req) == 'http'?http:https;
    const http_client = http_handler.request({
        host: req.headers.host,
        path: req.url,
        method: req.method,
        headers: req.headers,
        body: req.body
    },(resp)=>{
        res.writeHead(resp.statusCode,resp.headers);
        resp.pipe(res);
    });

    req.pipe(http_client);
};

http.createServer(app).listen(80);
https.createServer({
  // typical https options ommited for siplicity
},app).listen(443);
```

As you can see both `http` and `https` can be used as clients as well. I can detect if http or https using the `getProtocol` that can be used both at expressjs and other frameworks (such as connect).

Using that at section:

```
    const http_handler = getProtocol(req) == 'http'?http:https;
```

I decide whether to use http or https client for better emulation. Then I make the client using `http_handler.request` and I pipe the request using `req.pipe(http_client);`

At callback function provided in `http_handler.request` I also writhe the appropriate response and heads because by default `resp.pipe(res);` will send `200` status code, a thing that might not always be true (for example http redirects).

The `resp.pipe(res);` forwards only the body instead of the headers as well.Therefore, we must send them first.

---

## How to test it:

Using curl you can test it like this:

```
curl --resolve yahoo.com:443:172.21.0.2 --resolve yahoo.com:80:172.21.0.2 -vvv https://yahoo.com -k -A "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1 Camino/2.2.1"
```

Using `--resolve` I temporally override the dns resolution and I provide manually the appropriate IPS. Also, using the `-k` parameter I accept any certificate (it's ok for **local** development). With that, you can test a reverse proxy using custom ssl/tls certificates.